# Want to store photos like photo application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, photos

I would like to store severals photos like photo application, however i don't know exactly the objects what i need. If anyone know how to implement this way i'm interested.

A link to give you an idea: http://blog.photobox.fr/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/Album-iPhone5.jpg

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the PhotoViewer provided in three20 framework. It is exact replica of the Photos app of iPhone, if that's what you're looking for. You can find a tutorial [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1430/how-to-use-the-three20-photo-viewer).

Answer (score 1):

```
go to this link it help u
```

https://github.com/kirbyt/KTPhotoBrowser

Answer (score 0):

Having spoken to an Apple engineer on some of the optimizations that they went through on the Photos app, I can give you a couple of tips:

1. They never display back the original photo.  Because of a photo's size, they only take the original photo and save off a number of optimized thumbnail images.
2. The example image you show does not contain a series of thumbnail images.  Each row is actually a single image.  For selection, an overlay is placed in the exact size and dimension of the thumbnail image to give the impression that you are selecting a particular image.  This could be accomplished by using a table view, but it more likely just a scroll view.